# Nested XML schema, how to use JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm facing a quite big problem since even if I do a correct use of JAXB API to mapping an xml string to a java object I get stuck.
To save time, I will not write the real fields but the general schema of my XML:

```
<A>
   <B>
      <B1></B1>
      <B2></B2>
      <B3></B3>   
      <B4></B4>
      <C>  
         <D>
            <D1></D1>
            <D2></D2> 
         </D>
      </C>
      <B5></B5>
      <B6></B6>
   </B>
   <E> 
      <F>
         <F1></F1>
         <F2></F2>
         <F3></F3>
      </F> 
   </E>
   <G> 
      <G1></G1>
      <G2></G2>
      <G3></G3>
    </G>
</A>
```

So in this situation I have a class A build as,

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "A")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class A{
 
   @XmlElement(name = "B")
   private B objB;


   @XmlElement(name = "C")
   private String objC= "";

   @XmlElement(name = "E")
   private String objE= "";

   @XmlElement(name = "F")
   private F objF;

   @XmlElement(name = "D")
   private D objD;

   @XmlElement(name = "G")
   private G objG;
```

So the wrapper class A has an attribute of the object related to the proper portion of XML. Hence, each letter has its own class which represent an object inside my project.
Using this:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(A.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

StringReader reader = new StringReader("xml string here");
A element= (A) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

I cannot properly map my xml string in my custom nested object. So my goal is to map the whole xml string in the A class which will automatically map its attribute which are xml portion of the string as well. I also declare annotations @Xmlelement for each attribute in each sub-class. Lastly, E and C do not have a proper class since they act just as a sort of separator for respectively D class and F class so they have been simply declared as Strings in the main class A.

I never used JAXB for such complex data models so I do not know exactly how to proceed. Many thanks to whoever will reply.

Answer (score 0):

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "A")
public class A {

```
private B b;

private E e;

private G g;

@XmlElement(name = "B")
public B getB() {
    return b;
}

public void setB(B b) {
    this.b = b;
}

@XmlElement(name = "E")
public E getE() {
    return e;
}

public void setE(E e) {
    this.e = e;
}

@XmlElement(name = "G")
public G getG() {
    return g;
}

public void setG(G g) {
    this.g = g;
}
```

}

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class B {

```
private String B1;

private String B2;
private String B3;
private String B4;
private C c;
private D d;
private String B5;
private String B6;

@XmlElement(name = "B1")
public String getB1() {
    return B1;
}

public void setB1(String b1) {
    B1 = b1;
}

@XmlElement(name = "B2")
public String getB2() {
    return B2;
}

public void setB2(String b2) {
    B2 = b2;
}

@XmlElement(name = "B3")
public String getB3() {
    return B3;
}

public void setB3(String b3) {
    B3 = b3;
}

@XmlElement(name = "B4")
public String getB4() {
    return B4;
}

public void setB4(String b4) {
    B4 = b4;
}

@XmlElement(name = "C")
public C getC() {
    return c;
}

public void setC(C c) {
    this.c = c;
}

@XmlElement(name = "B5")
public String getB5() {
    return B5;
}

public void setB5(String b5) {
    B5 = b5;
}

@XmlElement(name = "B6")
public String getB6() {
    return B6;
}

public void setB6(String b6) {
    B6 = b6;
}
```

}

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "C")
public class C {

```
private D d;

@XmlElement(name = "D")
public D getD() {
    return d;
}

public void setD(D d) {
    this.d = d;
}
```

}

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "D")
public class D {

```
private String D1;
private String D2;

@XmlElement(name = "D1")
public String getD1() {
    return D1;
}

public void setD1(String d1) {
    D1 = d1;
}

@XmlElement(name = "D2")
public String getD2() {
    return D2;
}

public void setD2(String d2) {
    D2 = d2;
}
```

}

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "E")
public class E {

```
private F f;

@XmlElement(name = "F")
public F getF() {
    return f;
}

public void setF(F f) {
    this.f = f;
}
```

}

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class F {

```
private String F1;
private String F2;
private String F3;

@XmlElement(name = "F1")
public String getF1() {
    return F1;
}

public void setF1(String f1) {
    F1 = f1;
}

@XmlElement(name = "F2")
public String getF2() {
    return F2;
}

public void setF2(String f2) {
    F2 = f2;
}

@XmlElement(name = "F3")
public String getF3() {
    return F3;
}

public void setF3(String f3) {
    F3 = f3;
}
```

}

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class G {

```
private String G1;


private String G2;
private String G3;

@XmlElement(name = "G1")
public String getG1() {
    return G1;
}

public void setG1(String g1) {
    G1 = g1;
}

@XmlElement(name = "G2")
public String getG2() {
    return G2;
}

public void setG2(String g2) {
    G2 = g2;
}

@XmlElement(name = "G3")
public String getG3() {
    return G3;
}

public void setG3(String g3) {
    G3 = g3;
}
```

}

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thank you sir. I'll try my code again with this data model. Two more things: what if D can be repeated (array of object of class D) and F too? Why some classes such as G does not have the @XmlRootElement?

Comment: If you want to repeat D and F you have to take an arraylist of D objects.@XmlRootElement can be skipped for nested objects as it is used as the top(root) level of xml file.

Comment: JAXB is a java standard by which we can convert java objects into xml structures.In the above example the class A is the top level class which is the root element of the xml file.For any xml tag e.g <A></A> we have to define a class.Since class A has multiple nested xml tags , multiple java classes are defined for each tag.